# How to restore only one component in GKE backup

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Let's say I create a backup for mongodb and postgres.

```
kind: ProtectedApplication
apiVersion: gkebackup.gke.io/v1alpha2
metadata:
  name: BackupCandidates
  namespace: test
spec:
  resourceSelection:
    type: Selector
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: backup-candidates
  components:
  - name: mongodb-backup
    resourceKind: Statefulset
    resourceNames: ["mongodb"]
    strategy:
      type: BackupAllRestoreAll
      backupAllRestoreAll:{}
  - name: postgres-backup
    resourceKind: Statefulset
    resourceNames: ["postgres"]
    strategy:
      type: BackupAllRestoreAll
      backupAllRestoreAll:{}
```

How to restore only one component? Lets say postgresql's data became corrupted/lost..etc and I would like to restore it.

The official documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/add-on/backup-for-gke/how-to/restore-plan
says that I can use the `--selected-applications` flag but only for a ProtectedApplications as a whole. So I guess mongodb will be restored too.

So how can I restore only a subset of ProtectedApplication?